# Using launch image as ViewController background image

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I created my 3 launch images (Default Default@2x Default-568@2x) at their appropriate resolutions.  I'd like to use these images as the background image of my initial View Controller.

However, when I designed my launch images, I did it with the statusbar in mind and left that area blank.  When I try to set the background image of the View Controller to the launch image using the following code, my launch image begins at the bottom of my status bar and the blank area is visible. Essentially, my 640x1136 launch image is being squeezed into a 640x1096 space.  What is the proper way to do what I'm attempting?

```
   UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default-568h@2x"];
}
else{
    backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default"];
}

UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:backgroundImage];
[backgroundImageView setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview:backgroundImageView];
```

Update:

I replaced:

```
[backgroundImageView setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
```

With:

```
[backgroundImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,-20,self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height+20)];
```

And it seems to be behaving the way I want now.

Comment: Remove area blank from the image..

Comment: wait, you have a blank area in your image file?  Like part of the pixels?

Comment: Yes the top 20/40px are black.

If I remove the blank area from the image, when the app is launching the status bar covers part of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage]];
```

Also try not setting backgroundImageView's frame programatically.  It should already be the size it should be when you call `initWithImage:`.

Comment: When I try this my image doesn't get scaled down at all at is cut off.

Comment: Does it still leave the gap below the status bar?

Comment: Didn't understand you had a black bit on the image itself you were trying to hide.  In that case, try moving the center 20 points: `backgroundImageView.center = CGPointMake(backgroundImageView.x, backgroundImageView.y-20);`

Answer (score 0):

Make use of unedited image which does not contain the blank area. this will work fine.

Check replacing this  `[backgroundImageView setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];` with the following code.

```
  int statusBarHeight = statusBar.frame.size.height;

  backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,statusBarHeight,self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height-statusBarHeight);
```

Comment: I got something similar to this to work:    

    [backgroundImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,-20,self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height+20)];

Comment: I think you are using the edited image with the blank area ah? The above code would have worked fine for image with no blank area.